# File upload using Flatiron

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js, formidable

I am trying to do a file upload in Flatiron. Without using Flatiron (only Node), I was able to do a file upload using Formidable like so -

```
form = formidable.IncomingForm()
form.parse request, (error, fields, files) ->
   # upload done
```

However the same code does not work in Flatiron. It is hangs there after the first line -

```
form = formidable.IncomingForm()
app.log.info 'Form object made' # This is getting printed
form.parse @.req, (error, fields, files) ->
    app.log.info 'Upload done' # This is not getting printed
```

What am I missing here? There is no error as well.

Note - The code samples are in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Is `@.req` a typo or could it be the source of your trouble?

Comment: `@.req` is `this.req` and is the request object in flatiron. I don't think that is a trouble but I am not sure.

Comment: If there are other ways to upload a file in Flatiron, I'd like to know those as well.

Comment: `@.req` would compile to `this..req` with CoffeeScript. `this.req` should be referred to as `@req`. \[Edit\] I take it back, it appears CoffeeScript is smart enough to deal with the extra `.`. Learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file uploads with flatiron seems a bit of a mystery. I didn't find much information either. So here is my solution (as sticked together from pieces from the internet).

You have to turn buffer of in union / flatiron.plugins.http.

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.http, {buffer: false});
```

And you have to turn stream on in your post route.

```
app.router.post('/form', { stream: true }, function (){});
```

Here is a gist with working code: https://gist.github.com/ichbinadrian/4971260